# Location icon randomly appearing in status bar every hour

Tags: macos, ios

Since updating to 10.12.4, an icon has started appearing in my status bar 1-3 times every hour:

[image]

It looks like something's requesting access to my MacBook's location, but there's nothing in the privacy preferences that would indicate what:

[image]

I don't know what would be requesting my location: both Weather and Siri are disabled, and I have all "fancy" features turned off. The *"Setting Time Zone"* part is especially confusing, because I upgraded Sierra the same night daylight savings ended.

Seeing this pop up while programming is starting to get really distracting. Is there a way to hide it? Preferably by fixing whatever keeps causing it to appear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting Time Zone is a System Service. Press the Details button in your screenshot, then disable it.

[image]

As for why this is occurring now: 10.12.4 introduces Night Shift, which adjusts the display colours for night use. If you have the Sunset to Sunrise option selected, your location is used to determine when to adjust the display.

[image]

Comment: The padlock was the culprit here. Because I had everything disabled, I figured that was the reason the **Details** button was also disabled. I just hadn't clicked on it, which is why I couldn't find a fix in the first place... ugh. Thanks!