# Menu bar shows that macOS Sierra very frequently uses location services to check the time zone even though Setting Time Zone is disabled

Tags: menu-bar, geolocation

Ever since upgrading to macOS Sierra, I have been able to keep track of when programs use my location because the menu bar displays an icon whenever an app requests this information. I have noticed that about once per hour, the location services icon appears for a few seconds, and when I click on it it says "Apps requesting location: Setting Time Zone"

I've tried disabling automatic time zone detection in System Preferences (Under the Privacy > Location Services options), and this does not prevent this from happening. Here is what this setting looks like on my computer, note that the "Time Zone" box is already unchecked:

[image]

I looked at the list of other programs that have recently requested my location, and nothing unusual appears:

[image]

What is causing this, and is there any way to disable it? If this cannot be turned off, then is there a way to prevent it from appearing in the menu bar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Location icon randomly appearing in status bar every hour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280164/location-icon-randomly-appearing-in-status-bar-every-hour)

Comment: @Mateusz OP of this question has already disabled the Setting Time Zone option unlike that link, hence my solution over there won't work here — this isn't a duplicate?

Comment: @Mateusz My second screenshot in my answer shows what happens if you try to enable Night Shift's Sunset to Sunrise option when the Setting Time Zone option is disabled: it won't let you. It may be there's a bug that OP has stumbled across here, but that doesn't make it a duplicate either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue on macOS 10.12.6. Give this a try:

1. Under System Preferences > Date & Time > Time Zone: Uncheck "Set
   time zone automatically using current location"
2. Disable location services completely
3. Delete the file "/Library/Caches/com.apple.AutoTimeZone.plist"
4. Reenable location services again
5. Restart your computer

Does it solve your issue? [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/62vwsy/setting_time_zone_a_few_times_a_day/dft3ojc/)

Comment: This worked for me in Sierra (macOS X 12), but in High Sierra (macOS X13) I don't see a "com.apple.AutoTimeZone.plist" file in "/Library/Caches/" folder (in Finder or Terminal).